# Getting server error 500, 'Internal Server Error', but works fine on Postman, using httpclient in C#

Tags: c#, rest, desktop-application, dotnet-httpclient

Everything seems fine when I use Postman I get the right response, only using the code gets me error 500.
I checked up often before posting the question here.

```
 string host = "removed for privacy";
        string access_token = "removed for privecy"
        int profileId = 25; 
        string getTemplate = "/profiles/{0}/orders?order_status=new";
        string putTemplate = "/profiles/{0}/orders/{1}";
        string getPath;
        string putPath;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate });
        
        public User()
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(host);

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", access_token);

            getPath = string.Format(getTemplate, profileId);
            Uri.EscapeUriString(getPath);
        }

        public List<Order> GetNewOrders()
        {

            Console.WriteLine(client.BaseAddress + getPath);

            List<Order> orders = null;
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress + getPath).Result;
            Console.WriteLine(response);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

                orders = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Order>>().Result;               
            }
            else
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            }
            return orders;
        }
```

I get responses only in Postman, using the same url and `access_token`. I just removed then for privacy. Can you explain what's wrong with it and where is the missing part?

Comment: I suggesting capturing the HTTP traffic and comparing them line by line. You're probably missing a header or other token in your request.

Comment: As John Wu recommended. Fiddler is a good tool for capturing http traffic

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I called a https REST webservice in .NET Framework 4.7.2

If a request doesn’t work in your application but works in another API platform like Postman on the same machine within the same computer network, it indicates that the two requests are different.

To discover the difference I tried identify all headers sent by my app and those sent by Postman. In that time, to discover it, I made a simple webservice to return all received headers, but now I day, I could test the "Fiddler Classic"  that worked to this problem too
[Error 500 - Fiddler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAy2v.png)

In my case, I discovered that my app sent the "Expect" header and the postman didnt send it. When I forced to my app dont pass it, the request worked.

if the Fiddler Classic dont work to you, maybe my simple webservice can help you:

https://github.com/eliasedc/ApiGetHeaders

FYI, The solution is configured to start the three projects in the same time. I did this to demonstrate that the same request with the same code to bring different results between the .NET Framework and .NET Core clients (the Swagger works too)
[Same request with different results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57mF7.jpg)

Error 500 can be a lot of things and In that time I didn't find a answer that help me a lot, so, I really hope that this answer can help another devs.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by not setting any Authorization header.
In my case the access token was passed directly into the request body.